# How can I select a file without it opening?

Tags: pantheon-files, click

I've been trying for 5 minutes to select about 10 files and delete them.

But I can't select multiple items. How am I meant to do this? The ticks don't seem to affect it (but that might be bad mouse skills). Can I change the default from 1 click open to 2 click open?

Comment: This should probably be two questions...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Selecting files / folders** works fine for me in Pantheon Files by either:

1. Using and clicking the checkmark at the top left of an icon to select one or multiple entries.
2. Clicking and dragging the mouse on an empty area to make a rectangular selection area.
3. Pressing the control key (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>) before clicking on an icon also allows to select one or multiple files.

If you only want to select one file you can also just do a right click and choose the action immediately.

To **trash an item** just press delete (<kbd>del</kbd>).

If you have problems with selecting files / don't like the default behaviour you can [change the behaviour to open items on double click](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/38/how-can-i-disable-single-click-enable-double-click-in-files-to-open-an-item/39#39).

Comment: Yes: ["How can I disable single click / enable double click in Files to open an item?"](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/38/how-can-i-disable-single-click-enable-double-click-in-files-to-open-an-item/39#39)