# Double click default behaviour for all users?

Tags: pantheon, mouse, click

the solution mentioned in [Configure Files to use double click](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/38/configure-files-to-use-double-click)

> GSettings (recommended)
> Run the following command in terminal
> gsettings set io.elementary.files.preferences single-click false
> (To enable single-click again use true instead of false.)

seems to be valid only for the current user. Is there a way to set double click behaviour as a system wide default (for all users)?

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Elementary Tweaks](https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks) where you can change it and set permanent.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I would prefer a solution without installing external repositories because I want to use the setup for a computer pool which has to run very stable.