# How can I copy/paste the file NAME?

Tags: pantheon-files

When I do a rename of a file (or a folder) I want to be able to use copy/paste (<kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd>) !

When I try to do this (using keyboard shortcut or right click), the name gets validated (I am not in edition mode anymore) ... so I can't copy the name ! :(

As soon as I right click or use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key, the name is validated: I am not in edition mode of the name any more and that's the file that is selected and not the file name anymore.

**EDIT: Sept 2016**
This was due to the option to display circles when pressing CTRL (*Parameters=> Mouse* check *Reveal cusor position*: that stops the edit mode as soon as you press CTRL) !
This is still true for *Loki*.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What do you want? Rename with right click and the option rename or with the F2 Key. How do you use copy paste to rename? Ctrl+c, Ctrl+v copy or paste works on a selected text or a folder or a file. So you can select a folder, click f2 (text get automatically selected) ctrl+c and move to another folder and click f2 (text get automatically selected) and paste it with ctrl+v.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I select a file without it opening?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/26/how-can-i-select-a-file-without-it-opening)

Comment: What do you mean by validated? It exits the rename box? Ctrl + C should not do that. Are you using Luna or Freya?

Comment: @uomoinverde I'm fairly certain that that isn't what this poster is trying to ask.

Comment: I've edited my question. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

Well If you do want to copy and/or paste the name of files and folders heres the way:

- Right click on the folder and select properties

[image: the props]

- Here you will find at the top the name, all shortcuts work, eg `ctrl+c`

[image: props]

- Right click on the name and other options appear

[image: prop pro]

Comment: ok, but no, that's not an option ! Most of the time when I rename a file, I want to copy / paste the actual name to be able to rename that file or the next one.
I can do that in all File explorer, it's only with file explorer I can not do it !

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Freya or Loki so presumably it was a bug that has been fixed.