# Huge bug: copy/paste doesn't work in the pantheon-files rename menu

Tags: pantheon-files

You can see the proof here:
http://giphy.com/gifs/pantheon-files-rename-menu-bug-l4FGtN9vJ8HTtd9Dy/fullscreen

The problem is already described here: [How can I copy/paste the file NAME?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1895/how-can-i-copy-paste-the-file-name)

And the answer fom 'Aditya ultra' doesn't work. Nothing happens when you press on the 'paste' option.

But pressing 1) rename and 2)Ctrl + V works. It's very strange.

The issue is also present on another laptop where pantheon-files uses the default elementary theme, so the theme doesn't cause the issue.

It is really time to fix this, this is one of the most important things that users do with a file manager.

Answer (score 2):

I think this refers to a known regression due to r2522 that is fixed by r2524.  It should not have affected the stable release and the unstable branch should now be fixed.  Please advise which release and version this is affecting if this is not the case.

Comment: It affects the stable release (Files 0.3.2) So basically the version that everyone uses right now when they download elementary OS Loki 0.4 and update via AppCenter.  My question received down-votes, so I think that I need to explain something here for this kind of people. When someone like me posts these facts the developers have two options. 1) They do the work. They solve the posted bug and try to optimize the performance, stability and features of the specific app. or 2)  They don't do the necessary work, and the distro will go to the world of oblivion.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, the 'problem' or 'bug' is happening at the point where you click on the filename (when it is editable, in white text / green background) and it changes it's appearance back to white on dark gray.

Once it's white on dark gray, you are dealing with the file, not the filename.

When it turns white on dark gray, and you click 'Paste' then you are pasting whatever is on the clipboard to the file.

I'm about to install this OS for the first time, but it seems clear that you are a) copying the **file**, not the filename, and b) pasting (a file) to the **file**, not to the file name.

Comment: I literally wrote in the OP: "But pressing 1) rename and 2) Ctrl + V works." It's obvious that I know how to copy (and paste) the filename. (Ctrl+V would only work after a file name copy) My steps in the gif recording: 1) right click on a file name 2) left click on rename 3) right click in the blue field of selected text 4) left click on copy 5) richt click on the file name from another file 6) left click on rename 7) right click in the blue field of selected text 8) left click on paste. I should have reported this issue with elementary OS to the developers, not via this Q&A